# How to handle multiple individual json response?

Tags: javascript, java, json, gson

Actually I am doing some testing in which I am getting response from one of our endpoint which looks like multiple individual json objets and I need to convert them in such a form like a string or a single json object so that I can perform some action on them.

**Json response Example :-**

```
{"user_name":"testUser","email":"test@test.com"}
{"country":"Australia","Gender":"Male"}
{"type":"Customer_Account","membership":"Annual"}
```

Here the issue is I can not perform any operation until I convert it to some string or Json object.

And cannot control response as its coming from some third party application.

Any idea how to convert it using JavaScript or Java will be a great help.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON. How should the output look like?

Comment: This is what the issue is its not valid json but multiple individual valid json's.

Comment: So What is the expected result?

Comment: @Jakson would you be able to provide that API?

Comment: @RameshReddy sorry can not share that as it private to organization and somewhat confidential as well

Comment: Are all objects on separate lines?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming might useful

Comment: What does "Any idea how to convert it using JavaScript to Java will be a great help." mean? Do you need a JavaScript or a Java solution? How is Gson related to this at all?

Comment: @fluffy its a typo there I edited it and as far as Gson is concerned I am thinking if there is any way by which I can covert it to java object and then convert that object to json

Comment: @Jakson In Java, as it was already pointed out by Maurice Perry, you can use `BufferedReader` and its lines stream so that you could deal with each line (probably producing another stream and collecting it in a final result by using a collector). Having that, you don't need to spend Java heap by allocating intermediate strings that mimic JSON arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is in the source of the response, that is not a valid JSON. You can validate errors here: https://jsonlint.com/

Have you implemented the source of the JSON? If so you could make it a list of objects...

```
[{"user_name":"testUser","email":"test@test.com"},
{"country":"Australia","Gender":"Male"},
{"type":"Customer_Account","membership":"Annual"}]
```

If the source of the response is external (you can't modify it), it is possible to save the response into a String, then split the string into a list to iterate it to make the objects.

Hope this is somewhat helpful.

Comment: yeah I tried to save it as string but getting parsing error

Comment: The error would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

If your objects are separated by line breaks, you can read the stream line by line, and parse each line that should be valid JSON.

Otherwise, you can detect the end of an object by keeping track of the level of nested braces (increment for `{`, decrement for `}`).

Instead of parsing each object separately, you can also insert brackets and commas to form a valid JSON array, and then parse that array.

Answer (score 0):

Split the JSONs using regex and keep it in an array:

```js
let text = '{"user_name":"testUser","email":"test@test.com"}{"country":"Australia","Gender":"Male"}{"type":"Customer_Account","membership":"Annual"}';
const myArray = text.split(/(?=[{])/g);

let name = JSON.parse(myArray[0]).user_name;

console.log(myArray[0]);
console.log(name);
```

Now you can parse the strings as JSON.

Comment: I downvoted this. This answer: 1) ignores the fact that the response is a line-delimited JSON; 2) it ignores a possible way that the response may have nested objects and arrays; 3) regular expressions should never be used like that.

Comment: 1) I understood from OP post that he get that response and can store it as string, and later want to perform some operations, but can't parse because it's not a JSON valid string. 2) That's true, I will improve the answer. 3) Why not? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

Join them with comma `,` and put result in brackets `[]`:

```
[
    {"user_name":"testUser","email":"test@test.com"},
    {"country":"Australia","Gender":"Male"},
    {"type":"Customer_Account","membership":"Annual"}
]
```

after that use can use JSONObject class or other related things

Comment: and how should he join?

Comment: The question here is how to join ?

Comment: @Jakson What's the error? show us

Comment: While using it is JS it shows error as error: /script.js: Missing semicolon. And it pointing to missing comma between two json's

Comment: And in java it gives json.parser.ParserException Unexpected token { at position 18

Comment: This generates invalid JSON anyway: the last element of the wrapping array must not have a trailing comma.